# Finite rings of prime order must have a multiplicative identity

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, rngs

The standard definition of a ring is an abelian group that is a monoid under multiplication (with distributivity). However, there are some books that have a weaker definition implying that a ring only has to be closed under multiplication (no identity).

There is a problem in my algebra book asking me to prove that if a ring (defined in the second way) has $p$ elements, where $p$ is prime, and the multiplication is not trivial (i.e. sending everything to $0$), then the ring is forced to have a multiplicative identity.

Its seems like a trivial proof, but I just can't see what I'm missing.

What I have so far:
Given $R$ is a ring with $p$ elements and
$R$ is an abelian group of prime order, therefore it is cyclically generated, and of characteristic $p$ and isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. Essentially it boils down to showing $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is forced to have a multiplicative identity, but I just can't see where this comes from (every resource I found seems to take this as a fact). Since this is a requirement regardless of multiplicative structure, I can't just use the fact that $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} - \{ 0 \}$  is a group under the typical multiplication.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $x$ be a nonzero element of the ring. Then $R=\{0,x,2x,3x,\ldots,(p-1)x\}$
where $2x$ means $x+x$ etc. Then $x^2=jx$ where $1\le j\le p-1$.
Moreover $(ax)(bx)=abx^2=(abk)x$. All you need to do is to prove that for
some $a$, $(abk)x=bx$ for all $b$. (It's surely enough to do this for $b=1$).

Comment: Isn't it necessary to show that $x$ is not nilpotent?

Comment: The multiplication is nonzero, but if $x^2=0$....

Answer (score 1):

If $R$ is a ring of order $p$, then it injects into the ring $\text{End}(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ of endomorphisms of the abelian group $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.    How many elements does this ring have?

Comment: ...endomorphisms of the abelian group $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$...

Comment: Right; I'll clarify that.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the subset $Z ⊆ R$ of elements such that left-multiplication by $z ∈ Z$ does map everything on $0$, $Z$ is trivial because $R$ has non trivial multiplication, hence every non zero element $a$ of $R$ defines an automorphism of the abelian group $R$ which sends $x$ to $ax$ (because the kernel of each map is trivial) , hence we can define a map from $R\setminus\{0\}$ to the automorphisms group $\operatorname{Aut}R$ this map is injective, or $\operatorname{Aut}R$ has $p-1$ element then our map send a non zero element $a$ of $R$ on the identity morphism of $R$, we obtain $ax=x$ for every element $x$ of $R$.

Answer (score 0):

Go on a hunt for all the ways in which *R* can *fail* to be isomorphic to ℤ/pℤ, and demonstrate the failure of any of them to hold.

Consider the subset *Z* ⊆ *R* of elements such that left-multiplication by z ∈ *Z* **does** map everything to zero. We may easily show that *Z* is an ideal in *R*:

- For y,z ∈ *Z*, we have (y+z)r = yr + zr = 0+0 = 0 for any r ∈ *R*, so y+r ∈ *Z*;
- For any z ∈ *Z* and a,r ∈ *R*, we have (az)r = a(zr) = 0 and (za)r = z(ar) = 0; so az, za ∈ *Z*.

Well, really, we only needed the first of these two criteria, because it shows that (*Z*,+) must be a subgroup of the abelian group (*R*,+), which is of prime order. We know that *Z* ≠ *R*; so it follows that *Z* = {0}.

Okay then. If none of the non-zero elements map *everything* to zero via multiplication, perhaps some of them map *some* things to zero? Select a ∈ *R* \ {0} arbitrary, and consider the set *S*<sub>a</sub> = {b ∈ *R* | ab = 0}. Well, again we find that *S*<sub>a</sub> is an abelian subgroup of *R*, and again we know that *S*<sub>a</sub> is not allowed to be all of *R*; so we know that *S*<sub>a</sub> = {0}. That is, *R* contains no zero divisors.

Well, are there any non-zero elements such that multiplication is not invertible? Well, no: any a,b ∈ *R* such that ar = br for some non-zero r ∈ *R* would have the property (a − b)r = 0, so that a = b; so multiplication by elements of *R* \ {0} yield bijections on  *R* \ {0}.

This should now enable you to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

$\rm R = \{0,a,2a,\cdots,(p-1)a\}\ $ for $\rm\ 0 \ne a\in R\:$. So $\rm\ a^2 = k\:a\ $ and $\rm\ k \ne 0\:$ via multiplication nontrivial. Now $\rm\ j = 1/k\ \:mod\ p\ \Rightarrow\ ia\ ja\ = \ ijka\ =\ ia\ \Rightarrow\ ja = 1\:$.